# Is equisatisfiability an equivalence relation?

Tags: logic

I am trying to prove that equisatisfiability is an equivalence relation and I have to name the number of equivalence classes.

I know I have to prove that it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. 
This is what i have so far:

**(φ ≈ ψ) if φ is satisfiable ⇐⇒ ψ is satisfiable**

1. Reflexive: φ ≈ φ is true because when φ is satisfiable <--> φ is satisfiable
2. Symmetric: φ ≈ ψ implies  ψ ≈ φ?  Yes, coz  φ ⇐⇒ ψ is the same as ψ
   ⇐⇒ φ
3. Transitive: When φ ≈ ψ and ψ ≈ χ it implies that φ ≈ χ

Is my way of thinking correct? I am not really sure if this is enough for to prove it.

When it comes to the equivalence classes I am totally stuck. Maybe someone can help me here a little bit? Thank you.

Comment: It's very simple: what do you need to know to decide whether $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are in the same class?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi: I assume they are in the same class when both satisfiable or not?

Comment: Exactly.  How many classes does that give?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi: Well then 2. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Equivalence relation sounds like equivalent relation, but the two phrases are very different.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi: Ah, okay, so it is very simple. Thank you :)